# How to update/create many-to-many relational data in MVC Code-first using EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have pored through StackOverflow, Google and asp.net trying to find a clear cut, basic example of how to do this. All the examples have been abstract or involved complications that do not apply. I haven't been able to extract much useful from them. So far, none of them have completely answered my question or addressed my issue(s).

I am working on an MVC project with the following model:

Article.cs:

```
public class Article
{

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public Article()
    {
        Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
}
```

Category.cs:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
    }
}
```

ArticleEntities.cs:

```
public class ArticleEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

An article can have many categories and a category can belong to many articles.

So far I can save/update/create all the article fields except the Categories.

I am representing them as a checkboxes in the view. I can get the values for the selected checkboxes into the controller, but, every attempt I have made to store them in the db with the article has failed.

How do I:

1) When saving an edited article, update the existing relations in the relation table without creating duplicates?

2) When saving a new article, create the chosen relations in the relation table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you get a list of `CategoryId`s from the controller post action, a `List<int>` or more general just an `IEnumerable<int>`.

> 1) When saving an edited article, update the existing relations in the
>   relation table without creating duplicates?

```
Article article; // from post action parameters
IEnumerable<int> categoryIds; // from post action parameters

using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Load original article from DB including its current categories
    var articleInDb = ctx.Articles.Include(a => a.Categories)
        .Single(a => a.ArticleId == article.ArticleId);

    // Update scalar properties of the article
    ctx.Entry(articleInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(article);

    // Remove categories that are not in the id list anymore
    foreach (var categoryInDb in articleInDb.Categories.ToList())
    {
        if (!categoryIds.Contains(categoryInDb.CategoryId))
            articleInDb.Categories.Remove(categoryInDb);
    }

    // Add categories that are not in the DB list but in id list
    foreach (var categoryId in categoryIds)
    {
        if (!articleInDb.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId))
        {
            var category = new Category { CategoryId = categoryId };
            ctx.Categories.Attach(category); // this avoids duplicate categories
            articleInDb.Categories.Add(category);
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that the code also works when you have a `ArticleViewModel` instead of an `Article`, given that the property names are the same (`SetValues` takes an arbitrary `object`).

> 2) When saving a new article, create the chosen relations in the relation
>   table?

More or less the same idea as above but simpler because you don't need to compare with an original state in the database:

```
Article article; // from post action parameters
IEnumerable<int> categoryIds; // from post action parameters

using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    foreach (var categoryId in categoryIds)
    {
        var category = new Category { CategoryId = categoryId };
        ctx.Categories.Attach(category); // this avoids duplicate categories
        article.Categories.Add(category);
        // I assume here that article.Categories was empty before
    }
    ctx.Articles.Add(article);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: "I assume that you get a list of CategoryIds from the controller post action, a List<int> or more general just an IEnumerable<int>."

Comment: Yes, I am categoryIds in as a <int> collection (Ienumerable, actually). Everything looks like it should work, but one line of code won't compile: "if (!categoryIds.Any(c => c.CategoryId == categoryInDb.CategoryId))" I get an error that -'int' does not contain a definition for CategoryId.-

Comment: @panzerblitzer: Yes, that was a mistake, sorry. I've corrected the code (using `Contains`, see above). `if (!categoryIds.Any(c => c == categoryInDb.CategoryId))` would work as well.

Comment: Absolutely freaking awesome. Thank you so much for this. I've been trying to decipher others semi-applicable code to do this simple task for the last two days. This worked spot on, smooth as silk after the edit.