# Entity Framework inserting null record

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using the entity framework for a webapp I am working on.  The web app keeps track of venues.  Each venue can host several types of events.  I have a table with all the different type of event types (EventTypes) and another table that keeps track of which events each venue can have (VenueEventTypes), when I am adding a new venue I create a new VenueEventTypes collection which contains an EventType Propery and go out to the database and find the event type and add it to each of the VenueEventTypes.  The problem is when I save the venue it creates everything fine but it is adding an empty record in the database for the EventTypes, but the VenueEventType foreign key is point to the valid event type and not the newly create empty one.  Here is some code:

```
 public void addVenue(VEN_Venues venue)
    {
        using (var db = new VenueEntities())
        {
            var parish = from dbParish in db.VEN_Parishes
                         where dbParish.ParishID == venue.ParishID
                         select dbParish;

            venue.VEN_Parishes = parish.First();

            venue = this.processEventTypes(venue, db);
            db.VEN_Venues.AddObject(venue);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }



    private VEN_Venues processEventTypes(VEN_Venues venue, VenueEntities db)
    {
        foreach (VEN_VenueEventTypes eventType in venue.VEN_VenueEventTypes)
        {
            eventType.VEN_EventTypes = new EventTypeFacade().findEventTypes(eventType.VEN_EventTypes, db);
        }
        return venue;
    }
```

Could someone point me to the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are actually adding the `VEN_EventType` to the `venue.VEN_VenueEventTypes`.

You have to do something along these lines:

```
venue.VEN_VenueEventTypes.Add(eventType);
```

if you don't want any duplicates you will have to use attach:

```
venue.VEN_VenueEventTypes.Attach(eventType);
```

Comment: I am adding it the code behind for the page.  The problem is everything is set correctly in the DB, except there is a extra row getting added in the EventTypes table that has an id with the rest of the row null.

Comment: You need to use `Attach` to avoid duplicate row entries. You are creating a brand new `EventType` everytime you add it to the `venue.VEN_VenueEventTypes`. `Attach` will just add the relationship between `Venue` and `EventType` which is what you want. Take a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385429/how-to-update-create-many-to-many-relational-data-in-mvc-code-first-using-ef

Comment: The row is not a duplicate it is a row that has an ID with all the other fields null.  Everything else is correct in the table.  The foreign keys are correct just an unwanted record with null values are added.